# Javascript slider: How to set default opacity on page load

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, slider, opacity

I am using a javascript "slider" function to set the opacity of an image.

Even though I specify "value: 0.5;" all this does is set the slider "bar" **position** to 0.5 , it doesn't actually **change** the opacity to 0.5.

On page load, the default opacity is always 1.0. I can click on the slider bar (which is in the 0.5 position), and it will apply the 0.5 value, but I want to specify a default value when the page loads (and of course have the slider set to match it).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 0.5,
        orientation: "horizontal",
             slide: function(e,ui){
                     $('#box').css('opacity', ui.value)
             }                
        })
    });
 </script>

<style type="text/css">
#slider { width: 100px;}
#box {position:absolute; top:40px; left:0px; z-index:-1; opacity:0.5;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <p><div id="slider"></div>
    <div id="box">
    <img src="image.gif">
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried `value:1` ?

Comment: I would like the value to be 0.5, but the actual opacity is always 1.0 when the page loads, even though the slider is in the 0.5 position. You have to click on the slider to get it to be 0.5.

Comment: you could try after your slider intialisation $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 0.7 );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the jQuery fadeTo method to manipulate the opacity in a browser independent way.
See here: [jq-fadeto](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

Try it first in a JavaScript console directly on the image, like this

```
<img id="imageid" src="image.gif">
...
$('#imageid').fadeTo(0, 0.4);
```

Also check your events, the "slide" is used while sliding, you might use a handler for "change" or other event to get it right. Look here: [jq-slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change)

Comment: Got it!  I placed it just after: $(document).ready(function() {  and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove opacity in

```
 #box {position:absolute; top:40px; left:0px; z-index:-1; opacity:0.5;}
```

from your style and then try it

Comment: The .fadeTo worked.  FYI, changing the opacity in that style line had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

you could try after your slider intialisation $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 0.7 );